# Controlling how far to scroll in flat list. React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Good day guys , is there anyway I can control how far the flatlist can scroll ? I'm trying to make an image viewer. When there is multiple image , the user can scroll to the 2nd image without reaching the 3rd image. Thank you. Expected outcome :

[image]

Comment: You can achive this by implementing [**`react native snap carousel`**](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel)

Comment: Thx , i archive what i wanted. Does carousel have similar method like scrollToIndex in flatlist ??

Comment: This has all the controls which are showing in your picture.

Comment: I have used this and it's working great.

Comment: Yeah , it's amazing. Thank you so much for telling me to use carousel

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use a library like react native snap carousel

or use the function of scrollToIndex inside any function ,so that you can control which index the user goes  ==

```
   scrollToNext(){
    this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: newIndex});
}

<Flatlist
 ref={ref => {
            this.flatListRef = ref;
          }}
/>
```

hope it helps. feel free for updates